# Converting data types for python and django

Tags: python, django

I have two main variables, `week_order_overall_total` which is a custom python money data type using this (https://github.com/mirumee/prices) and then the actual integer references below (5, 200, 15 etc).

When I try I do a calculation with the two using `payout = week_order_total_card - hm_fees`, I get an error message:

> '>=' not supported between instances of 'Money' and 'int'

I imagine this is because there are two different data types being used. I have tried resolving it using `int(week_order_overall_total)` but that doesn't work.

CODE:

```
if trial_status =="yes":
    if admin_value <=5:
        hm_fees=5
    else:
        hm_fees=admin_value
elif early_customer =="yes" and week_order_overall_total >=1 and week_order_overall_total <= 200:
    hm_fees=15
elif week_order_overall_total == 0:
    hm_fees=0
elif week_order_overall_total >= 1 and week_order_overall_total <= 200:
    hm_fees=20
elif week_order_overall_total >= 201 and week_order_overall_total <= 400:
    hm_fees=35
else: 
    hm_fees=55

payout = week_order_total_card - hm_fees
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do it the other way.. convert your integer value to money then compare money to money.

Answer (score 0):

Use week_order_total_card.value instead